# How to remove the margin in section in bixby

Tags: bixby, bixbystudio

This is a situation where sectioning is absolutely necessary.

I want to remove the margin between sections.

how do i do?

testview.view.bxb ↓

```
layout{
        section{
          content{
            compound-card{
              content{
                paragraph{
                  value("testtesttesttesttesttesttesttesttest")
                }
                 paragraph{
                  value("testtesttesttesttesttesttesttesttest")
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
        section{
          content{
            compound-card{
              content{
                paragraph{
                  value("testtesttesttesttesttesttesttesttest")
                }
                 paragraph{
                  value("testtesttesttesttesttesttesttesttest")
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
```

image ↓

[image]

[Problem]

```
testtesttesttesttesttesttesttesttest
testtesttesttesttesttesttesttesttest

testtesttesttesttesttesttesttesttest
testtesttesttesttesttesttesttesttest
```

[i want]

```
testtesttesttesttesttesttesttesttest
testtesttesttesttesttesttesttesttest
testtesttesttesttesttesttesttesttest
testtesttesttesttesttesttesttesttest
```

help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The additional space between two sections is not removable. It is there by design to split two different sections.

However, in your code, there is no need to do different section, as I would demo later

1. use new line "\n" in the paragraph value
2. use different paragraph in the same section

I would also recommend watch [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Abwc1tK0uZA) to learn more about different component in Bixby result-view.

```
result-view {
  match: StructB (this) 
  message: template ("Sample view") 
  render {
    // assume always single item, demo purpose only
    layout {
      section {
        content {
          paragraph {
            value: template ("#{value(this.aaa)}\n#{value(this.bbb)}\n#{value(this.ccc)}\n#{value(this.ddd)}")
          }
          paragraph {
            value: template ("I can do more here")
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

There is no need for compound card as well, here is the result. Please take note the additional space between two paragraphs.
[image]

Here is the content of StructB for your reference
[image]

Comment: You are welcome. If the answer works, please accept the answer so it can help more developers. Thanks!